# percentage values in translate(x,y,z) not working

Tags: css, css-transforms

I had animations using translate a 2D translate. But I would like to enforce hardware acceleration and hence used `translate3d()`. Here is my CSS:

```
.hand {
  position:fixed;
  top:-60%;
  left:50%;
  width:20%;
  margin-left:-10%;
}

.handmovedown {
  transform: translate3d(0%,110%,0%);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%,110%,0%); /** Safari & Chrome **/
  -o-transform: translate3d(0%,110%,0%);/** Opera **/
 }

.objecttransition {
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear; /** Chrome & Safari **/
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear; /** Firefox **/
    -o-transition: all 0.5s linear; /** Opera **/
}
```

HTML:

```
<img  id='Hand'  class="hand objecttransition"  src="css/images/hand.gif">
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Hand").addClass("handmovedown");
});
```

Now in the CSS when i just used translate(0%,110%) everything worked fine. I'm not to sure why this isn't working as the browser dev tools dont pick up any errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Mozilla Developer Networks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function#translate3d%28%29).

> <sup>**tz**</sup>
>       Is a  representing the z component of the translating vector. It can't be a `<percentage>` value; in that case the property
>   containing the transform is considered invalid.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Z82W/) *(Used `px`)*

Comment: Can I ask then, how does one deal with different screen sizes? As using px means different positioning on different devices. How would I go about then making animations once to fit different mobile device screens?

Comment: @Roberto Use jQuery to animate the object, by making the object `position: absolute;` and tweak the position of the element using `.animate()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The reason I dont want to use .animate is because this is meant to be a phonegap application and the .animate() doesn't work very well in phonegap

Comment: @Roberto Oh, I don't have much knowledge about the phonegap, but you can try using CSS keyframes too

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking about responsiveness in your comments, that would be the way:

There is not much support (real working support), but you should be able to use vh:

```
transform: translate3d(10%,20%,50vh);
```

Right now, FF handles that ok, Chrome allows you to use it (won't break) but won't calculate ok.